# openssl android ndk-build change path

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, native, ndk-build

I'm trying to compile openssl to **Android** based on:

https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android

I'm trying to run **ndk-build** but I get the following error:

> make: /home/aaa/tools/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found

How do I change the location to one of this two?

> /home/aaa/tools/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
>
> /home/aaa/tools/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

Or how should I compile this to solve a missing include?

The Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

subdirs := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/,$(addsuffix /Android.mk, \
        crypto \
        ssl \
        apps \
    ))

include $(subdirs)
```

Comment: How are you invoking ndk-build? What is the content of Application.mk?

Comment: I add to the question @bullsy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change variable NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION in the Application.mk file. You can read more about Application.mk and it difference with Android.mk [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/ndk/guides/application_mk.html)

Comment: Thanks do you know how can I solve the missing include #include <openssl/aes.h> // the include of openSSL to android?

Comment: You should put an includes in your project, then set up a LOCAL_C_INCLUDES variable to it. You can read the description of this and other .mk variables here http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/ndk/guides/android_mk.html

Comment: I make the question, if you have time. I believe that that is the way but is not working... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456444/openssl-in-android-add-library-to-g-command/35459234#35459234