# "openssl/aes.h: No such file or directory" under Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, openssl, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile to android environment. And because of that I get the following error:

```
error: openssl/aes.h: No such file or directory
```

I find some solution in stack but, I don't get how to end the process to be able to compile.

I already compiled one version of [openssl](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg) were should I add the libs? or how can I generate the *.a?

Do you know how can I add this library to the **arm-linux-androideabi-g++** that I need to run to be able to pass this problem?

Comment: Also see [OpenSSL and Android](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[1]** Get openssl library which has **aes.h file** in its include folder.

**[2]** If you have compiled openssl library in your lib folder then add to **-lssl or -lopenssl** to your command line.

Comment: but where i can add? That is the problem :(

Comment: try compiling somewhat like:  gcc -I/home/src/openssl/include -L/home/src/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto

Comment: just make sure you have .lib files in openssl lib folder

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find openssl includes: [openssl](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android/tree/master/include/openssl)

Download this includes and put them in some folder in your project, i.e. project_dir/module_dir/jni/openssl-includes.

Then you need set a LOCAL_C_INCLUDES variable in your Android.mk (which also is in jni folder:
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ./openssl-includes

After that, you can include files in openssl-includes folder directly by name, i.e.:

```
#include <aes.h>
```

If you need an *.a file as output, you should include BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY in Android.mk, if you need a *.so lib, include BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY.